# Node.js how to define a buffer object i have

Tags: node.js, buffer

So im trying to try stuff with buffers i opened a file in buffer mode then i copied it, but how do i define it back in a variable? Like so i can give the buffer object to someone else and they can assign it as buffer and use it normally i tried googling around and testing stuff. Hope someone can help if you didn't understand anythin feel free to ask.
More details:

```
const fs = require("fs");

const f = 
fs.readFileSync("path/to/file.txt")
f
// now a buffer
// copied buffer and kept it
// now how do i turn it back into a buffer object for later use?
```

For example i have

```
<Buffer 53 45 43 52 45 54 20 4d 45 53 53 41 47 
45 20 50 41 53 53 57 4f 52 44 20 3d 0a 44 72 6d 
43 6b 4c 38 56 71 45 76 48 4f 70 6c 4d 61 77 52 
59 33 4e 31 6d ... >
```

How would i enter it to node? If i just pasted it it as it is or as string won't detect it as a buffer dunno if this is possible

Answer (score 0):

Use `Buffer.from(string);`

```
const fs = require("fs");

const f = fs.readFileSync("path/to/file.txt");

let st = f.toString();
let new_f = new Buffer.from(st);

//Now new_f is the buffer object 'f' you got from reading the file.
```

Comment: Thanks but not exactly what i meant, what if i shared the Buffer object to another person? How would they parse it back to a buffer and use it